# How to convert struct array to binary array C#

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, marshalling

Here I have two method can parser struct to byte[] , And byte[] to struct .

So how can I parser "struct array" to byte array , and parser byte array to struct array.
Like this:

```
byte[] getBytes<T>(T[] str) where T : struct
T[] fromBytes<T>(byte[] byte) where T : struct
```

//---- here is struct to byte[] --- byte[] to struct ---

```
byte[] getBytes<T>(T str) where T : struct
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        byte[] arr = new byte[size];

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(str, ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, 0, size);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        return arr;
    }

    T fromBytes<T>(byte[] arr) where T : struct
    {
        T str = new T();

        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(str);
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);

        Marshal.Copy(arr, 0, ptr, size);

        str = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, str.GetType());
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

        return str;
    }
```

Comment: You're working with unmanaged memory structures and unmananged pointers, but yet you don't know how to handle an array?

Comment: @Gvs Yes , actually I not really unstand how this method work . I just google it , and I found this solution. 
but for my case I need convert "struct array" to byte array. So I have no idea how to modify this method.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

```
T[] GetStructs<T>(byte[] arr) where T : struct
{
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(default(T));
    int len = arr.Length / size;
    T[] result = new T[len];

    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        Marshal.Copy(arr, i * size, ptr, size);
        result[i] = (T)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(T));
    }
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    return result;
}

byte[] GetBytes<T>(T[] structAry) where T : struct
{
    int len = structAry.Length;
    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(default(T));
    byte[] arr = new byte[size * len];
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(structAry[i], ptr, true);
        Marshal.Copy(ptr, arr, i * size, size);
    }
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);

    return arr;
}
```